# how do I read data from txt file and make it as lists in python

Tags: python

I am trying to read data from hi.txt file, and the contents of hi.txt shows on the picture I uploaded.

What I am trying to do is to make data looks exactly like below

```
X = [[0, 0], [0, 1], [1, 0], [1, 1]]
Y = [[0], [1], [1], [0]]
```

what I have in my code is

```
X=[]
Y=[]
```

and, hi.txt is located in c: looks like

```
#XOR
#X1 X2 Y
0 0 0
0 1 1
1 0 1
1 1 0
```

And, what am I supposed to do to make the data structure like that by reading 
txt data..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `numpy.loadtxt`:

```
In [30]: arr = np.loadtxt('Desktop/a.txt')

In [31]: X, Y = arr[:,:2], arr[:,2:]

In [32]: X
Out[32]: 
array([[ 0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  0.],
       [ 1.,  1.]])

In [33]: Y
Out[33]: 
array([[ 0.],
       [ 1.],
       [ 1.],
       [ 0.]])
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do it I think.

```
x=[]
y=[]
with open("myfile.txt", encoding="utf-8") as file:
    arr_content = file.readlines()
    for eachline in arr_content:
        values = eachline.split()
        x.append([values[0],values[1]])
        y.append(values[2])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
with open("hi.txt") as f:
    X ,Y = [], []
    for line in f:
        if not line.startswith("#"):
            x1, x2, y1 = line.strip().split()
            X.append([x1, x2])
            Y.append([y1])
```

Comment: You are appending the whole list to itself.

Comment: Now you are overwriting ´y´, aren't you?

Comment: While this might be *the answer* to the question, and the one who asked might be contempt with it, it would be nice if you could add some explaination on what you did, so it also helps further readers, that may stumble across this question.

Answer (score 0):

```
X = [[None for x in range(2)] for y in range(4)]
Y = [[None] for y in range(4)]
i=0
with open('hi.txt', 'r') as file:
    for row in file:
        if row[0]!="#":
            a, b, c = row.split()
            print ("\nReading row # %d from file: %s") %(i, row)
            X[i]=[int(a),int(b)]
            Y[i]=[int(c)]
            i+=1
            print "X[] is now:", X
            print "Y[] is now:", Y

print ("\n\nFinal Output:")
print (X)
print (Y)
```